# how to change this node js json response

Tags: node.js, json

i have a proble here,i need to change the json response but i dont know how to change it i already try many thing but nothing success and how i can get the recent response is cause i follow tutorial in youtube. i use node js for the language

```
{
   "status": 200,
   "values": {
       "Luffy": {
           "id_mahasiswa": 1,
           "nim": 312060003,
           "nama": "Luffy",
           "jurusan": "Bajak Laut",
           "matakuliah": [
                 "Pemrograman Dasar",
                 "Algoritma",
                 "Matematika"
           ],
           "sks": 10
        },
        "Sanji": {
            "id_mahasiswa": 3,
            "nim": 312060012,
            "nama": "Sanji",
            "jurusan": "Koki",
            "matakuliah": "Matematika",
            "sks": 28
       }
   }
}
```

but i want to make it like this

```
{
   "status": 200,
   "values": [
       {
           "id_mahasiswa": 1,
           "nim": 312060003,
           "nama": "Luffy",
           "jurusan": "Bajak Laut",
           "matakuliah": [
                 "Pemrograman Dasar",
                 "Algoritma",
                 "Matematika"
           ],
           "sks": 10
        },
        {
            "id_mahasiswa": 3,
            "nim": 312060012,
            "nama": "Sanji",
            "jurusan": "Koki",
            "matakuliah": "Matematika",
            "sks": 28
       }
   ]
}
```

for the code

```
exports.okNested = (values, res) => {
    const hasil = values.reduce((akumulasikan, item) => {
        if(akumulasikan[item.nama]){
            const group = akumulasikan[item.nama]
            if(Array.isArray(group.matakuliah)){
                group.matakuliah.push(item.matakuliah)
            }else{
                group.matakuliah = [group.matakuliah, item.matakuliah]
            }
        }else{
            akumulasikan[item.nama] = item
        }
        return akumulasikan
    }, {})

    const data = {
        "status": 200,
        "values": hasil
    }

     res.json(data);
     res.end()
}
```

Thank you very much for those who help me, sorry for bad english

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want array, instead of an object.  Your posted expected result still shows an object however.

```
{
 values:[]
}
```

To get that, you would convert the returned object's values into an array.

```js
result.values = Object.values(result.values)
```